# Environment Tier: Web Server or Worker for Setting up Elastic Beanstalk TVM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The tutorial for [Token Vending Machine for Anonymous Registration - Sample Java Web Application](http://aws.amazon.com/code/8872061742402990) is out of date. In particular the current Beanstalk console has an option for Web Server or Worker (which is not covered in the tutorial) for the Environment Tier field under Environment Type. I presume for setting up a TVM I would want a server but I wanted to confirm before saving the config. So, server or worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be web server for TVM example.
AWS Elastic Beanstalk [added](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/background-task-handling-for-aws-elastic-beanstalk/) support for worker tier in December 2013.